# Android libgdx: NullPointerException on SQLiteOpenHelper database

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sqliteopenhelper, interfacing

I am trying to write a code in my game to save the score when the player dies. For that purpose I implemented an `interface` to use `SQLiteOpenHelper` (the `interface` is in the core project and the `SQLiteOpenHelper` is in the android project). For anyone doesn't know, the interface thing is for this purpose [see](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) code

The problem is that when I want to save the score (int) the game crashes and an `NullPointerException` appears.

My code:

In the **android project**, the database using `SQLiteOpenHelper`:

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements DataBaseInterface {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gamescore";

private static final String TABLE_SCORE = "score";

private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_SCORE = "score_value";

public DataBase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_SCORE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORE + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_SCORE + " INTEGER" + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_SCORE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SCORE);

    onCreate(db);
}

public void addScore(int score) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_SCORE, score);

    db.insert(TABLE_SCORE, null, values);

    db.close();

}

public String[] getAllScores() {

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORE;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    int i = 0;

    String[] data = new String[cursor.getCount()];

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        data[i] = cursor.getString(1);

        i = i++;

    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return data;
}}
```

Next, the main class of the android project with the database implemented:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    initialize(new CatchEmAll(new DataBase(this.getBaseContext())), config);
}
}
```

In the **core project**, the interface that is implemented in the database of the android project:

```
public interface DataBaseInterface {
void addScore(int score);
String[] getAllScores();
}
```

In the main class of the core project (CatchEmAll.java), the implementation of the interface:

```
public class CatchEmAll extends Game {

private final DataBaseInterface db;

public CatchEmAll(DataBaseInterface db) {
    this.db=db;
}
```

Finally the game screen of the game (in core project), where I want to save the score using that interface:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
private Game game;
private Stage stage;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private Viewport viewport;

private DataBaseInterface db;


...

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act();
    stage.draw();

    ...

    if (Enemy.collides(player)) {
      ...

      db.addScore(score);
    }
```

The null exception is in db.addScore(score);

I guess i'ts because I need to use the `DatabaseInterface` created in the main class of the core project `(CatchemAll.java)` but I don't know how can I do that and if this is the problem or not. Use Android API in `libgdx` is a nightmare.

**logcat error**:

> 08-23 14:13:41.961 7568-7596/borruey.catchemall E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 282
>       Process: borruey.catchemall, PID: 7568
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void borruey.catchemall.databasescore.DataBaseInterface.addScore(int)' on a null object reference
>           at borruey.catchemall.screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:182)
>           at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
>           at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:495)
>           at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1571)
>           at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1270)
>   08-23 14:13:45.978 7568-7568/borruey.catchemall E/AndroidGraphics: waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing

Comment: sir post the logcat error please

Comment: @ALTegani done!

Comment: did you define db instance?

Comment: @ALTegani the problem is that i don't know how i can instance the db, because the database class is in the android project, and I need to use the db in the core. So, I need to use the interface and I don't know where I need to make the instance.

Comment: If i define the interface, I get the error "DataBaseInterface' is abstract; cannot be instantiate".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exact understand where you have null exception, in what line? But i mentioned that you declare `KEY_SCORE` as a `TEXT`

```
String CREATE_SCORE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORE + "("+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ KEY_SCORE + " TEXT" + ")";
```

And trying to add `int` for it:

```
values.put(KEY_SCORE, score);
```

If it not an problem, it will be a problem in future.

Comment: Thanks for that! Now instead of TEXT I have INTEGER. The null exception is in the game screen class. In db.addScore(score);